# Python GUI based on a database. Error 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python

I am trying to get my python code to work. I believe I am close but I keep getting the error 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'select'. Whenever I click on one of my buttons in the GUI. I am not sure what is left to do to fix it.

(Sorry if the formatting of the question is not proper. First time posting.)

The code will be below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('Contacts.db')

def insert():
    try:
        db.insert(firstn_text.get(), lastn_text.get())
        firstn_entry.delete(0, END)
        lastn_entry.delete(0, END)
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Contact Added')
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror('Failure', e)

def view():
    try:
        phone = db.select(firstn_text.get(), lastn_text.get())
        phone_entry.delete(0, END)
        phone_entry.insert(END, phone[0][2])
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror('Failure', e)

root = Tk()

root.title('Contacts')
root.geometry('300x200')

firstn_text = StringVar()
lastn_text = StringVar()

firstn_label = Label(root, text='First Name')
firstn_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

lastn_label = Label(root, text='Last Name')
lastn_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

firstn_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=firstn_text)
firstn_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

lastn_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=lastn_text)
lastn_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

phone_entry = Entry(root)
phone_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

submit_btn = Button(root, text='Submit', command=insert)
submit_btn.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

search_btn = Button(root, text='Search', command=view)
search_btn.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code format was close :-) Just use ``` instead of '''.

Comment: The error explains itself doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no `select` and `insert` methods for `connection` or `cursor` objects in sqlite3.

You have to `execute` SQL queries.
Support your database has a table `contacts`, with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, phone TEXT)
```

Then inserting would look like this:

```
def insert():
    try:
        
        db.execute(
           "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
           (firstn_entry.get(), lastn_entry.get(), phone_entry.get())
        )
        firstn_entry.delete(0, END)
        lastn_entry.delete(0, END)
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Contact Added')
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror('Failure', e)
```

Selecting is more complicated. It doesn't matter if you select by `firstname`, `lastname` or `phone`, there might be several matching rows.

So for displaying the contacts, maybe use a `treeview`.